# Vue backgroundImage not showing from local directory

Tags: vue.js, styles

I am trying to assign a background image to my lists items i v-for that will get data from objects like in code below. I have no problem when I am putting https of random img from web but I don't have img showing if I link to my local asset folder. Can you direct me where is the problem please.

My storage file:

```
    data() {
    return {
      portfolioListData: [
        {
          id: 'id-1',
          date: '2018',
          title: 'Stitching Fairy',
          description: 'Web Design / Development',
          link: 'https://www.stitchingfairy.com/index.html',
          routLink: '/stitchinFiary',
          backgroundImg: {
            backgroundImage: 'url(./assets/StitchingFairyBackground.jpg)'
          } 
        },
        {
          id: 'id-1',
          date: '2018',
          title: 'Stitching Fairy',
          description: 'Web Design / Development',
          link: '~https://www.stitchingfairy.com/index.html',
          routLink: '/stitchinFiary',
          backgroundImg: {
            backgroundImage: 'url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/watercolor-textured-background-picture-id887755698?k=6&m=887755698&s=612x612&w=0&h=_yEUF8gLpWjZv5IgwuWkecNVt4X4P7vpuFBKCWIuR44=)'
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      resources: this.portfolioListData
    };
  }
```

**My element markup:**
**strong text**

```
<template>
  <li>
    <div :style="backgroundImg" class="portfolio-element">
      <base-container>
        <base-half-half>
          <template v-slot:leftSide>
            <div class="left">
              <p>{{ date }} </p>
              <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
              <p>{{ description }}</p>
            </div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:rightSide>
            <div class="right">
              
            </div>
          </template>
        </base-half-half>
      </base-container>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['date', 'title', 'description', 'backgroundImg']
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.portfolio-element {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 20rem;
}
</style>
```

**List Element**

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <portfolio-element
        v-for="res in resources"
        :key="res.id"
        :date="res.date"
        :title="res.title"
        :description="res.description"
        :backgroundImg="res.backgroundImg"
        ></portfolio-element>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>

import PortfolioElement from './PortfolioElement.vue';
export default {
    inject: ['resources'],
    components: {
        PortfolioElement
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `require()` for your local assets

change this line:

```
backgroundImage: 'url(./assets/StitchingFairyBackground.jpg)'
```

to this:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${require('./assets/StitchingFairyBackground.jpg')})`
```

Comment: Thank you, It solved the problem. So if I understand it correctly "require" prevent webpack for optimisations and tree shaking?? During my trials, I discovered that if I put background -image in scoped style Vue add some extra text to the URL of the img like ./img/imgtitle28938983.jpg.

Comment: yes, you can read more about asset handling here : https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have also faced this issue what I did was that to create a url and to make a get request to the image to my backend where the image is locally stored.

In Vue Template,

```
<div  :style="{ 'background-image': `url(${srcdest})` }" />
```

the srcdest variable should have full url location of your image  like(https:localhost:(server port no)/+ your file image)

You can checkout this link which I referred to solve the issue
[here](https://www.positronx.io/vue-image-preview-tutorial/)